# Drawer Toggle button transitions with fragment navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, material-design

I'm trying to write an app with a toolbar navigation using fragments exactly like the Gmail app: You have a drawer toggle shown as the "hamburger" button, when you click on a mail, the hamburger makes a transition to the back button and vice-versa.

As of now, I've been able to achieve something very close to what I want, except for the toggle button that is not "animating" from Hamburger to back arrow.

What I did is to bind a Listener for the BackStack in the mainActivity:

```
SupportFragmentManager.AddOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
```

Then from Fragment A, I can load fragment B adding it to the Back Stack:

```
ResultFragment fragment = new ResultFragment();
this.Activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
   .Replace(Resource.Id.main_fragment, fragment)
   .AddToBackStack("results")
   .Commit();
```

In the Main Activity the Listener checks for Backstack, if is not empty it switches the hamburger to the backbutton:

```
bool canGoBack = SupportFragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount > 0;
if (canGoBack)
{
      //Showing Back Button
      if (!_toolbarNavigationListererSet)
      {
         drawerToggle.DrawerIndicatorEnabled = false;
         SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

         BackHandler backHandler = new BackHandler(this);
         drawerToggle.ToolbarNavigationClickListener = backHandler;
         _toolbarNavigationListererSet = true;
      }

}
else
{
       //Show the hamburger
       SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
       drawerToggle.DrawerIndicatorEnabled = true;

       drawerToggle.ToolbarNavigationClickListener = null;
       _toolbarNavigationListererSet = false;
 }
```

The drawerToggle.ToolbarNavigationClickListener changes the behaviour of the back button to call the back button press event, like:

```
Activity.OnBackPressed();
```

nothing more.

I understand that by doing this, the hamburger is hidden and the back button is shown, and viceversa, so I'm sure that's the reason why I cannot see the animation.

What am I missing? Thank you for your help.

P.s. The code is written in C# as I'm using Xamarin.Android but Java code and/or Android Native Code is well accepted as a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a animation  when you press the back button, like this :

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.OfFloat(0f, 1.0f);
anim.AddUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener(this));
anim.SetInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
anim.SetDuration(500);
anim.Start();

public class AnimatorUpdateListener : Java.Lang.Object, ValueAnimator.IAnimatorUpdateListener
{
     private MainActivity mContext;

     public AnimatorUpdateListener(MainActivity context)
     {
         mContext = context;
     }

     public void OnAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator)
     {
         var slideOffset = (System.Single)valueAnimator.AnimatedValue;
         mContext.drawerToggle.OnDrawerSlide(mContext.drawerLayout, slideOffset);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works good from back-button to hamburger (Had to change from OfFloat(0f, 1.0f) to OfFloat(1.0f, 0f)) but does not work from hamburger to back-button. To be more precise, works only if I `awayt Task.Delay(500)` before setting `drawerToggle.DrawerIndicatorEnabled = false;`